# Copy BufferedImage to clipboard

Tags: java

How do I store a BufferedImage into the system clipboard?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is working code taken from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/333565/GUI/java/BufferedImage-System-Clipboard) tested successfully

```
package org.life.java.so.questions;

/**
 * @author Jigar
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CopyImagetoClipBoard implements ClipboardOwner {
    public CopyImagetoClipBoard() {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Dimension screenSize  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Rectangle screen = new Rectangle( screenSize );
            BufferedImage i = robot.createScreenCapture( screen );
            TransferableImage trans = new TransferableImage( i );
            Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            c.setContents( trans, this );
        }
        catch ( AWTException x ) {
            x.printStackTrace();
            System.exit( 1 );
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] arg ) {
        CopyImagetoClipBoard ci = new CopyImagetoClipBoard();
    }

    public void lostOwnership( Clipboard clip, Transferable trans ) {
        System.out.println( "Lost Clipboard Ownership" );
    }

    private class TransferableImage implements Transferable {

        Image i;

        public TransferableImage( Image i ) {
            this.i = i;
        }

        public Object getTransferData( DataFlavor flavor )
        throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
            if ( flavor.equals( DataFlavor.imageFlavor ) && i != null ) {
                return i;
            }
            else {
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException( flavor );
            }
        }

        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[ 1 ];
            flavors[ 0 ] = DataFlavor.imageFlavor;
            return flavors;
        }

        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor flavor ) {
            DataFlavor[] flavors = getTransferDataFlavors();
            for ( int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++ ) {
                if ( flavor.equals( flavors[ i ] ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get away with passing null instead of an implementation of ClipboardOwner.

Answer (score 6):

Jigar's code does indeed store a BufferedImage into the clipboard, although to be specific, it puts a screen-capture of the entire screen into the clipboard.

This may or may not be what you were after. In case you wanted to copy your own specific `BufferedImage`, in order to accomplish this, I replaced the constructor from Jigar's example with a `copyImage()` method.

```
public class CopyImagetoClipBoard implements ClipboardOwner
{
    public void copyImage(BufferedImage bi)
    {
        TransferableImage trans = new TransferableImage( bi );
        Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        c.setContents( trans, this );
    }
```

Remove the `main()` method within his class too.

You can then copy your BufferedImage with code such as this:

```
    BufferedImage bim;
    // set bim to your desired BufferedImage content
    // ...
    CopyImagetoClipBoard ci = new CopyImagetoClipBoard();
    ci.copyImage(bim);
```

Comment: Good stuff, but no need to create a whole new class there.

Comment: Oh, wait. Never mind. If anyone else thought like me, note that `CopyImagetoClipBoard` is a `ClipboardOwner`.

Answer (score 1):

as a static accessable util, a modified version of RAnders00

```java
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ClipboardUtil {
    private static final Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    private static final ClipboardOwner owner = new Owner();
    
    
    public static void copy(BufferedImage img) {
        copy(new TransferableImage(img));
    }
    public static void copy(Transferable trans) {
        c.setContents(trans, owner);
    }
}
class Owner implements ClipboardOwner {

    @Override
    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard arg0, Transferable arg1) {
        System.out.println( "Lost Clipboard Ownership" );
    }
    
}
class TransferableImage implements Transferable {

    Image i;

    public TransferableImage( Image i ) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public Object getTransferData( DataFlavor flavor )
    throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        if ( flavor.equals( DataFlavor.imageFlavor ) && i != null ) {
            return i;
        }
        else {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException( flavor );
        }
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[ 1 ];
        flavors[ 0 ] = DataFlavor.imageFlavor;
        return flavors;
    }

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor flavor ) {
        DataFlavor[] flavors = getTransferDataFlavors();
        for ( int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++ ) {
            if ( flavor.equals( flavors[ i ] ) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't error, but the clipboard is empty after this call? (I'm on Mint 20.3)

Answer (score 0):

A bit more minimized/modernized version of the static utility version by @ope for Java 17.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ClipboardUtil {
    
    private static final Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    
    public static void copyToClipboard(BufferedImage img) {
        clipboard.setContents(new TransferableImage(img), null);
    }
    
    private record TransferableImage(Image i) implements Transferable {
        
        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor)
                throws UnsupportedFlavorException {
            if (flavor.equals(DataFlavor.imageFlavor) && i != null) {
                return i;
            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[1];
            flavors[0] = DataFlavor.imageFlavor;
            return flavors;
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            DataFlavor[] flavors = getTransferDataFlavors();
            for (DataFlavor dataFlavor : flavors) {
                if (flavor.equals(dataFlavor)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```