# Image on Clipboard

Tags: java, image, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy BufferedImage to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552045/copy-bufferedimage-to-clipboard)

So, I have the following:

```
BufferedImage image = img.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);

ImageSel imageSel = new ImageSel(image);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard()
    .setContents(imageSelection, null);
```

I am implementing a basic MS Paint-like program. This is supposed to be a part of the 'cut' function. I'm just gonna give information on the parts:

img - an image of the my panel which represents the drawing canvas. 
ImageSel - a class implementing transferable. 
image - the section of img which I want to cut out.

Anyway, it works. The problem however is that the image I get from this is just a blank and black image with nothing else on it. Can someone please help by pointing me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't ordinarily need to paint it, would I? I have only used it for writing to a file and for this so far.

Comment: The key is likely in your Transferable class, ImageSel. Can you tell us more about this? What DataFlavor(s) have you given it?

Comment: Consider creating a small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your error. Your program should use an image that is freely available online and should have no local dependencies like on a local image or a databse. This way we all can run, test and modify your code, hopefully figuring out a solution. This is called creating an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Have a look at the link as it's a pretty useful concept.

Comment: have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552045/copy-bufferedimage-to-clipboard

Comment: Let's try to find the problem. First of all, save your 'img' to disk. Is it ok? Then save your `image` to disk. Is that ok, or black? If everything is ok, then the problem is with your `ImageSel`.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. I figured it out. I had to paint img. I guess it has to do with the way I have written the rest of it.