# How to right click / copy an image from a JLabel

Tags: java, copy, jlabel

I was wondering if it was possible to be able to allow the user to copy an image from a JLabel?

If so could someone please tell me what I need to search for in the java docs please.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some effort: yes. You need to define an action on that label so that if the user clicks on it, an image is copied into the clipboard.

**Further Reading**

- [How to write a mouse listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)
- [Copy BufferedImage to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552045/copy-bufferedimage-to-clipboard)