# Can you copy an image to the clipboard?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, copy-paste

Is there a way to right click, select copy, and then have that image copied to your clipboard? The idea would be to be able to copy the image and be able to paste it into an application like PowerPoint.

[image: JFrame with image]

Comment: does this help? https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-copy-image-to-clipboard-example/

Comment: Can you replace the MetaFrame with JFrame? How would I use the code to use it with a JFrame?

Comment: Is it an image you are displaying in you `JFrame`? If that's the case, everything you need to replace from the example code, is how to get that image. However, if you want to export the contents of your frame (ie. an image of the components), you will need to render your frame into a `BufferedImage` first. These are two separate problems.

Comment: It is an image yes. The goal is to copy the image in the Jframe, and paste it into another program

Comment: [Copy BufferedImage to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552045/copy-bufferedimage-to-clipboard)